# Chrome browser - "Only local connections are allowed" - browser launches properly but test cases stops and URL is empty

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When the tests starts and I run Chrome browser using WebDriver version 85. I get the following message in console.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.83 (94abc3121ae0c9a4cb5f035431c8adfb13245875-refs/branch-heads/3142@{#2321}) on port 46427
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Chrome does launch but when this is triggered in console, the test fails and stops and URL in browser is set to "data:,"

This is my dependency in pom file, and I am using Chrome version 85

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please post your code too.

Comment: The cited message is not an error and can be observed in "good" runs too.